# Autosum in multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have data in "n" cells in columns above Range "C11:C12"
Also I have data in "m" cells in columns above Range "C100:C101"

I need to sum these cells.

Without vba, if I select "C11:C12" and "C100:C101" together and then press Ctrl+=, the job is done. But I wonder if it is possible with small vba code?

Comment: Why does it need to be one line?

Comment: With one line I mean it is done in multiple locations at once. In this example I have given two ranges but actually there can be hundreds of non-continuous ranges in which I need this formula. I just want to avoid writing separate sum code for each range. So with one line I meant a small code.

Comment: You should, really, attempt this yourself and post your attempt in your question.

Answer (score 1):

VBA macros can be recorded.

Go to the "developers" tab (you might reconfigure Excel in order to make this visible), in there you have the opion "Record macro".

Comment: That's my go to answer - Have you tried recording a macro.  Common sense prevails! ;o)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
Sub Tester()
    'pass worksheet and a variable number of range addresses
    AutoSumRanges ActiveSheet, "C3:C5", "C11:C15", "A1:A3"

End Sub


'add a SUM() beneatch each range, on the worksheet "ws"
Sub AutoSumRanges(ws As Worksheet, ParamArray ranges() As Variant)
    Dim rng As Variant
    For Each rng In ranges
        With ws.Range(rng)
            .Cells(.Cells.Count).Offset(1, 0).Formula = _
                "=SUM(" & .Address(False, False) & ")"
        End With
    Next rng
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, is it possible without a loop? As I need it to be calculated for 100s of ranges simultaneously.